# Slow growing integer sequence that is periodic modulo primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, asymptotics, intuition, fibonacci-numbers

I'm looking for a slow growing integer sequence that is periodic modulo primes.

Essentially, the absolute value of each digit should be small.

**EFFECTIVENESS**

I've devised a measure of how effective the sequence is.  We take the $n$th value, and find for $f(n)$, the $n$th number:

$$f(n) = 2^{mn}$$

We measure the period of the sequence modulo $p$.  For example, the period modulo $p$ could be $p^2$.  We'll call this value, whatever it is, $f(p)$, which in the example is $f(p)=p^2$.

The measure is then:

$$f(p)^m$$

Ideally, this should be less than $p$.

**AN EXAMPLE**

Consider the Fibonacci numbers.  They are given by the exact formula, [as given in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio):

$$\text{Fibonacci}(n) = \frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\varphi-\psi}$$

where $\varphi \approx 1.61$ and $\psi \approx -0.62$.  Thus this function is bounded above by $O(1.61^n) = O(2^{\log_2{(1.61)}}) = O(2^{0.68n})$

We also know that the Fibonacci numbers are periodic modulo each prime $p$, and depend on the previous 2 values.  Thus there are at most $p^2$ combinations of previous values modulo $p$, and so the period is at most $p^2$ modulo $p$.

Thus, the effectiveness measure gives $m=0.68$ since $f(n) = 2^{0.68n}$.  It gives $f(p) = p^2$ as given above.  Combined, this gives $f(p)^m = (p^2)^{0.68} \approx p$.

**WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR**

Something that gives an effectiveness measure < $p$.  For example, a measure of $p/\log{(p)}$ would tie the best known result in the problem I'm working on.

Comment: Maybe it's helpful to note that the period of the Fibonacci numbers mod $p$ for $p$ prime is always at most $4p$, according to the Wikipedia article on Pisano periods: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period

Comment: I don't get the $f(n) = 2^{mn}$ and effectiveness part.

Comment: @user1952009:  We try to define the size of the $n$th value in terms of the function $2^{mn}$.  So, for example, if the actual size of the number is $4^n$, this is equal to $2^{2n}$.  If the size of the actual number is $\sqrt{n}$, this is equal to $2^{1/2n}$ and so $m = 1/2$.  In essence, I'm trying to convert the size of the $n$th number into a formula of the form $2^{m\cdot n}$, in order to get a value for $m$.  This may be easier said than done.

Comment: then write $g(p) = \frac{\ln f(p)}{p \ln(2)}$ and define your "effectiveness" in term of the values of $g$

Comment: In what sense is $(p^2)^{0.68}\approx p$? Also, you should explicitly rule out constant sequences.

Comment: For that matter, any polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients gives a sequence which is periodic modulo every integer $m$ with period $m$, and which grows much more slowly than the Fibonacci numbers. What "effectiveness measure" results from linear polynomials? quadratic? etc.

Comment: @GregMartin:  I wasn't being very exacting.  I just meant that it's close to $p$, since it is $p^{1.36}$.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to treat $p$ and $p^{1.36}$ as equivalent while highlighting the difference between $p$ and $p/\log p$.

Comment: @GregMartin:  Sorry, I now believe I wrote this too hastily.  But you are onto something with the polynomials.  They have period $p$ modulo $p$, and they are $O(2^{\epsilon n})$ for all $\epsilon > 1$, if I'm not mistaken.  This is all that I was looking for.  If you can show this $\epsilon $ bounds, which should be easy, I will accept the answer.  That's all I was really looking for, so thank you very much!

Comment: @MattGroff and $f(n)$ is the slowest growing strictly increasing sequence, that is $\bmod p$ periodic for every $p$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(n)=n$ has period $p$ modulo every prime $p$, and grows so slowly that it should give you a suitably small effectiveness measure.